# Set FFmpeg Process Priority with 2 Pass Encoding

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I'm using [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) with PowerShell.

I'm trying to set the Process Priority while using FFmpeg's [2 Pass](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass) Encoding.

The script works with 1 Pass and CRF Encoding.

---

**Script**

When Pass 1 finishes, it launches FFmpeg again for Pass 2.

Note: Pass 1 outputs to NUL, Pass 2 outputs the video file.

```
(Start-Process ffmpeg -NoNewWindow -Wait -ArgumentList '-i "C:\Path\video.mpg" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000K -pass 1 NUL' -PassThru).PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::AboveNormal; 

(Start-Process ffmpeg -NoNewWindow -Wait -ArgumentList '-i "C:\Path\video.mpg" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000K -pass 2 "C:\Path\video.mp4"' -PassThru).PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::AboveNormal
```

---

**Problem**

Using `-Wait` causes this PowerShell error:

```
Exception setting "PriorityClass": "Cannot process request because the process (14324) has exited."
```

But without `-Wait` the second pass never starts and I get this FFmpeg error:

```
Failed to initialize encoder: Invalid parameter
Additional information: rc_twopass_stats_in.buf not set.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would be looking for is `Wait-Process`.

You will need to lose the `-wait` as that command waits for the process to exit before running the next part of the script

```
($Process = Start-Process ffmpeg -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList '-i "C:\Path\video.mpg" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000K -pass 1 NUL' -PassThru).PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::AboveNormal; 
Wait-Process -Id $Process.id
($Process = Start-Process ffmpeg -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList '-i "C:\Path\video.mpg" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000K -pass 2 "C:\Path\video.mp4"' -PassThru).PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::AboveNormal
Wait-Process -Id $Process.id
```

You can verify the process has exited by using `$Process.HasExited`

```
($Process = Start-Process ffmpeg -NoNewWindow -Wait -ArgumentList '-i "C:\Path\video.mpg" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000K -pass 1 NUL' -PassThru).PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::AboveNormal; 
Wait-Process -Id $Process.id
$Process.HasExited
($Process = Start-Process ffmpeg -NoNewWindow -Wait -ArgumentList '-i "C:\Path\video.mpg" -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000K -pass 2 "C:\Path\video.mp4"' -PassThru).PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::AboveNormal
Wait-Process -Id $Process.id
$Process.HasExited
```

Comment: It looks like it's working, I'm going to do some more testing and get back to you.

Comment: I have another question for you. How to get Process Priority working with a Loop for Batch Processing files. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62074449/6806643