# Start-Process with Process Priority in Loop doesn't recognize variable

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach

I'm using [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) with PowerShell.

I have a loop that goes through a folder of `mpg` files and grabs the names to a variable `$inputName`.

FFmpeg then converts each one to an `mp4`.

---

#### Works

Batch Processing

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Path\" -Filter *.mpg; 

foreach ($f in $files) {

    $inputName = $f.Name; #name + extension
    $outputName = (Get-Item $inputName).Basename; #name only

    ffmpeg -y -i "C:\Users\Matt\Videos\$inputName" -c:v libx264 -crf 25 "C:\Users\Matt\Videos\$outputName.mp4"
}
```

---

#### Not Working

Batch Processing with Process Priority

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "C:\Path\" -Filter *.mpg; 

foreach ($f in $files) {

    $inputName = $f.Name; #name + extension
    $outputName = (Get-Item $inputName).Basename; #name only

    ($Process = Start-Process ffmpeg -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList '-y -i "C:\Users\Matt\Videos\$inputName" -c:v libx264 -crf 25 "C:\Users\Matt\Videos\$outputName.mp4"' -PassThru).PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::AboveNormal;
    Wait-Process -Id $Process.id 

}
```

If I set the Process Priority using `Start-Process` `PriorityClass`, the `$inputName` variable is no longer recognized.

```
Error:
C:\Users\Matt\Videos\$inputName: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets go over a few basic things.

In powershell we love piping `|`, It allows use to pass the information from one command to another command.

A good example of this is the `ForEach` you have.

Instead of `Foreach($F in $Files)` you can pipe `|` into a `foreach-object`

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Path\" -Filter *.mpg | Foreach-Object{
    $_
}
```

When Piping `|` a command powershell automatically creates the variable `$_` which is the object that is passed in the pipe `|`

The next thing is there are 2 types of quotes `"` and `'`.

If you use `'` then everthing is taken literally. Example

```
$FirstName = "TestName"
'Hey There $FirstName'
```

Will return

```
Hey There $FirstName
```

While `"` allows you to use Variables in it. Example

```
$FirstName = "TestName"
'Hey There $FirstName'
```

Will return

```
Hey There TestName
```

Now one last thing before we fix this. In powershell we have a escape char ` aka a tick. Its located beside the number 1 on the keyboard with the tilde. You use it to allow the use of char that would otherwise break out of the qoutes. Example

```
"`"Hey There`""
```

Would return

```
"Hey There"
```

OK so now that we covered the basics lets fix up the script

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\Matt\Videos\" -Filter *.mpg -File | Foreach-Object{
    ($Process = Start-Process ffmpeg -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "-y -i `"$($_.FullName)`" -c:v libx264 -crf 25 `"C:\Users\Matt\Videos\$($_.Name)`"" -PassThru).PriorityClass = [System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass]::AboveNormal;
    Try{
        Wait-Process -Id $Process.id
    }catch{
    }
}
```

In the case above I changed

Add `-File` to the `Get-ChildItem` to designate that you only want Files returned not folders

Pipe `|` into a `Foreach-Object`

Changed the Outside Brackets in the `-ArgumentList` to be double quotes `"` instead of literal quotes `'`

Removed the `$InputName` and `$OutputName` in favor of the `Foreach-Object` variable `$_`

Comment: I'm having a few problems. I getting `Wait-Process : Cannot process request because the process (16032) has exited.`. I copied your script exactly.

Comment: I need the paths wrapped in double quotes, if there's a space in the path or name FFmpeg won't recognize it, it thinks the space is starting the next command. I found I can escape them `".

Comment: @MattMcManis I updated the script to include error handling

Comment: @MattMcManis also if you read the post you would have seen I talked about the escape char :)