# FFmpeg Process Priority at screenrecording

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg, screen-recording, thread-priority, gdigrab

I made formula for screenrecording via FFmpeg, and it works with Counter-Strike and Dota 2.
But it doesn't work with World of Tanks. So I faced with troubles. World of Tanks crashs after few minutes. And speed of recording is less then 1x (about 0.87x and it become slower and slower). So I think that I need to raise up the priority process of FFmpeg.
Look for test of it on my Youtube Channel: [my test of ffmpeg screen recording](https://youtu.be/NMnPe9J_vYM)

So I would like to set 'High' or 'Realtime' priority for this process **automatically**!

But right now I can do it via 2 ways:

1. via Task Manager;
2. via second PowerShell Window and second "copy-paste".

But both methods require a time (5-20 seconds). It is no good.
I cannot to set `Start-Process ffmpeg -NoNewWindow -Wait -ArgumentList` for setting PriorityClass as here [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62052197/launch-process-with-priority) because my ArgumentList of FFmpeg is too huge.
And I cannot `start-process pwsh -ArgumentList` for new powershell window for setting PriorityClass. It write me about an error.
My tested formula for Youtube:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel +repeat+level+info `
-f dshow -thread_queue_size 8192 -audio_buffer_size 100 -rtbufsize 2147M `
-i 'audio=@device_sw_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\{8E146464-DB61-4309-AFA1-3578E927E935}' `
-f dshow -thread_queue_size 8192 -audio_buffer_size 100 -rtbufsize 2147M `
-i 'audio=@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{472DBE92-04B3-48AB-A937-ED4CD6A85625}' `
-f gdigrab -hwaccel_device cuda -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -video_size 1920:1080 -thread_queue_size 8192 -draw_mouse 1 -show_region 0 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -rtbufsize 2147M -probesize 500M -analyzeduration 500M -framerate 60 -i desktop `
-noautoscale -shortest `
-map '0:a:0' -c:a copy -f wav "FFmpeg_Screen_Recording_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss).wav" `
-map '1:a:0' -c:a copy -f wav "FFmpeg_WebCAM_Recording_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss).wav" `
-map '2:v:0' -c:v h264_nvenc -gpu 0 -vsync 1 -r 60 -video_size 1920x1080 -video_track_timescale 60 -copytb 0 -delay 0 -rc constqp -qp 0 -rc-lookahead 0 -zerolatency 1 -maxrate:v 512M -bufsize:v 512M -pix_fmt yuv444p -profile:v high444p -preset p1 -tune ull -level 6.2 -coder vlc -weighted_pred 0 `
-f mov "FFmpeg_Screen_Recording_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss).mov"
```

My current formula for High priority - first tab:

```
start-process pwsh -ArgumentList '-noexit' 
Get-Process -name 'pwsh' | foreach { $_.PriorityClass = "High" }
$startExe = ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel +repeat+level+info `
-f dshow -thread_queue_size 8192 -audio_buffer_size 100 -rtbufsize 2147M `
-i 'audio=@device_sw_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\{8E146464-DB61-4309-AFA1-3578E927E935}' `
-f dshow -thread_queue_size 8192 -audio_buffer_size 100 -rtbufsize 2147M `
-i 'audio=@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\wave_{472DBE92-04B3-48AB-A937-ED4CD6A85625}' `
-f gdigrab -hwaccel_device cuda -hwaccel cuda -hwaccel_output_format cuda -video_size 1920:1080 -thread_queue_size 8192 -draw_mouse 1 -show_region 0 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -rtbufsize 2147M -probesize 500M -analyzeduration 500M -framerate 60 -i desktop `
-noautoscale -shortest `
-map '0:a:0' -c:a copy -f wav "FFmpeg_Screen_Recording_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss).wav" `
-map '1:a:0' -c:a copy -f wav "FFmpeg_WebCAM_Recording_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss).wav" `
-map '2:v:0' -c:v h264_nvenc -gpu 0 -vsync 1 -r 60 -video_size 1920x1080 -video_track_timescale 60 -copytb 0 -delay 0 -rc constqp -qp 0 -rc-lookahead 0 -zerolatency 1 -maxrate:v 512M -bufsize:v 512M -pix_fmt yuv444p -profile:v high444p -preset p1 -tune ull -level 6.2 -coder vlc -weighted_pred 0 `
-f mov "FFmpeg_Screen_Recording_$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss).mov"
```

Second tab (second copy-paste action):

```
Get-Process -name 'ffmpeg' | foreach { $_.PriorityClass = "High" }
```

**How can I do it in the only one action?**

Comment: If I use a lot of " and a lot of ,
as I got in one anser, it don't work too.
`[error] Could not find audio only device with name ... among source devices of type audio.`
`I/O error`
`InvalidOperation: $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss) The property 'PriorityClass' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set`
I just copy-pasted, and it don't work.

Comment: Look for screenshot https://ibb.co/GktfnFJ

Comment: At screenshot above you can see, that here are 2 problems
1) system cannot see my Sennheiser GSP 550 but see `virtual-audio-capturer`
2) system cannot understand that `$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss)` is not applicable for `PriorityClass`

Comment: Look for my first-ever formula in my Question https://ibb.co/3WfMyMR

Comment: Later I modified formula: https://ibb.co/FzZqXwk But I need to use 2 PowerShell tabs in any way for stetting process priority of ffmpeg

Comment: My later FFMPEG formula  https://justpaste.it/1q1w7